# Highest value of a row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, max

I searched and found many results using "Grep highest value of a row in MySQL" but I don't understand the results.

I have a row which primary key value is 4 and there are another 8 values.
Those are `45  78 89 54 98  14  19  70`. I want to select the highest value, ie `98` from this row. How do I do this ?

My database table name is `class6A`

[image: table with sample data]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [**GREATEST()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function on all the columns

```
SELECT
GREATEST
(bangla_1st,bangla_2nd,english_1st,english_2nd,math,social_science,religious,science)
HighestValue
FROM class6A
WHERE roll = 4;
```

If any of the columns are NULL, then make the NULL the value 0

```
SELECT
GREATEST
(
    IFNULL(bangla_1st,0),
    IFNULL(bangla_2nd,0),
    IFNULL(english_1st,0),
    IFNULL(english_2nd,0),
    IFNULL(math,0),
    IFNULL(social_science,0),
    IFNULL(religious,0),
    IFNULL(science,0)
) HighestValue
FROM class6A
WHERE roll = 4;
```

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

In the future, you may add another subject to or remove a subject from the student record.

Here is another method using Dynamic SQL that figures out the subjects present in the table

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1048576;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('IFNULL(',column_name,',0)')) INTO @grades
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema=DATABASE() AND table_name='class6A'
AND column_name NOT IN ('roll','student_name');
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT GREATEST(',@grades,') HighestValue FROM class6A WHERE roll=4');
PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```